# get unhashable type dict error when using flask-mongoengine and flask-marshmallow

Tags: python, flask

I'm building API using flask, flask-mongoengine, and Flask-marshmallow. I get 'unhashable type dict' error when i try to return my db data using marshmallow.

this is my model:

```
from app import db

class Post(db.Document):
    title = db.StringField(max_length=128)
    body = db.StringField()
```

and this is my view:

```
from flask import jsonify
from app import ma
from app.models import Post

class PostSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('title', 'body')

post_schema = PostSchema()
posts_schema = PostSchema(many=True)

@mod_post.route('/post/')
def post():
    all_post = Post.objects
    print(all_post)
    result = posts_schema.dump(all_post)
    return jsonify(result)
...
```

I'm following the marshmallow tutorial here: http://flask-marshmallow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

but, unfortunately the error occured. Any advice guys?

Answer (score 0):

Detailed error message would help. From what I immediately see is that you getting result of `Schema.dump` and pass it to `jsonify()` but result is actually a tuple of dumped data and errors. You should start with doing it like that:

```
result, errors = posts_schema.dump(all_posts)
if errors:
    return jsonify({'error': errors.messages})

return jsonify(result)
```

Then you can add code to account for dump errors.

Answer (score 0):

Just change a return: 
`return posts_schema.dump(all_post, many=False)[0], 201`